# CURL: compose method POST when HTML page has scripts

Tags: html, bash, curl, https

I'm trying to write a bash script to auto send complaints for hundreds of spammed links of the type:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/hash
used only as redirection to well know crime domains.

The right address to complain for this kind of spammed links is:
https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report

Normally for situation like that, I use curl with the scheme:

1. download home page
2. parse home.html to look for form parameters and method POST
3. send a curl answer with the needed parameters

Something like this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# input parameters
name=""   # put here the user name
email=""      # put the google email
option="Google App Engine"
date="07/24/2021"
details="https://script.google.com/macros/s/<hash>"

# configuration variables
reportURL="https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report"
pars="-s -S -L -b cs.txt -c cs.txt" # curl default parameters
if (test -e "cs.txt" ) then { rm cs.txt ; } fi

# 1) download homepage ...
file=home.html
url=$reportURL
curl -o $file $pars $url

# 2) parse homepage to extract parameters ...
var1=`cat $file | grep <something1>`
var2=`cat $file | grep <something2>`
data="name=$name&email=$email&option=$option&&date=$date&detail=$detail&FORM=$var1&SUBMIT=$var2"

# 3) send the answer with parameters ...
file=reply.html
url=$reportURL # may differ
curl -o $file $pars --data "$data" $url
```

But with this home page downloaded at step 1, I can find form parameters, many scripts but no method POST (while I can find "POST" in the script code).

How can I construct the curl answer?

note: As the page uses HTTPS, it is also not easy to capture and understand the browser traffic with Wireshark

Edit: added here the relevant parts of the html page:

```
...
<label class="cc" for="fullname_prefill">
 <span class="contact-form-label__text">Name</span>
</label>
<input aria-label="Name" id="fullname_prefill" maxlength="1000" name="fullname_prefill" value=" " type="text"></div>

<label class="cc" for="email_prefill_req">
 <span class="contact-form-label__text">Email address *</span>
</label>
<input aria-label="Email address *" id="email_prefill_req" maxlength="1000" name="email_prefill_req" type="text">
 <div class="validation-message custom" tabindex="-1">Please provide a valid email address.</div>

...

<div class="list-item" aria-labelledby="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service--google_app_engine">
   <label class="material-radio">
      <input class="material-radio__input" aria-label="Google App Engine ( *)" id="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service--google_app_engine" name="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service" value="google_app_engine" type="radio">
      <label class="material-radio__label-text" for="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service--google_app_engine">
         <div class="material-radio__circle"></div>
         <div class="material-radio__fill"></div>
         <span class="contact-form-label__text">Google App Engine</span>
      </label>
   </label>
</div>

...

<label class="cc" for="abuse_date">
   <span class="contact-form-label__text">Abuse date</span>
</label>
<input aria-label="Abuse date" id="abuse_date" name="abuse_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field" data-contact-form-field-required="true" data-enable-form-single-attachments="true" data-frd-context-type="TYPE_CORE" data-frd-context-type-number="15" data-frd-identifier="IDENTIFIER_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION" data-frd-identifier-number="8000020" data-frd-v2-identifier="IDENTIFIER_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION" data-frd-v2-identifier-number="8000020" data-frd-value-type="VALUE_TYPE_STRING" data-frd-value-type-number="2" data-page="1" data-type="TEXTAREA" data-use-new-uploads-component-for-cufs="true">

...

<div class="field" data-enable-form-single-attachments="true" data-frd-context-type="TYPE_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-context-type-number="0" data-frd-identifier="IDENTIFIER_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-identifier-number="0" data-frd-v2-identifier="IDENTIFIER_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-v2-identifier-number="0" data-frd-value-type="VALUE_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-value-type-number="0" data-page="1" data-type="HIDDEN" data-use-new-uploads-component-for-cufs="true">
   <input name="Subject" value="Google Cloud Platform Abuse Report" type="hidden">
</div>
<div class="alert-area"></div>
<div class="button-bar">
   <span class="notification-area" tabindex="-1"></span>
   <div class="buttons">
   <button class="submit-button material2-button material2-button--filled" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="contact-form__gdpr-dialog">
     <div data-page-data-key="gdpr-dialog-privacy-policy" style="display:none">https://myaccount.google.com/privacypolicy?hl=$0</div>
       <div class="gdpr-dialog__text">Some <a class="gdpr-dialog-trigger" href="#">account and system information</a>
        will be sent to Google, and support calls and chats may be recorded. We will use
...
```

Comment: Do you have access to the HTTPS' page server?  You could turn on log_forensic to get more details of the requests.  You should add to the question sample pages with good and bad parsing so we can se what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry I can't understand. How can I turn on log_forensic ? How can I add the downloaded page, this stackoverflow form say it is too long?

Comment: No need to put the entire pages, just the offending section.  Read [mcve].  For log_forensic, look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html, it *might* help.

Comment: here the pertinent html parts: 
...
<label class="cc" for="fullname_prefill">
 <span class="contact-form-label__text">Name</span>
</label>
<input aria-label="Name" id="fullname_prefill" maxlength="1000" name="fullname_prefill" value=" " type="text"></div>

<label class="cc" for="email_prefill_req">
 <span class="contact-form-label__text">Email address *</span>
</label>
<input aria-label="Email address *" id="email_prefill_req" maxlength="1000" name="email_prefill_req" type="text">
...

Comment: ...
<div class="list-item" aria-labelledby="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service--google_app_engine">
   <label class="material-radio">
      <input class="material-radio__input" aria-label="Google App Engine ( *)" id="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service--google_app_engine" name="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service" value="google_app_engine" type="radio">
      <label class="material-radio__label-text" for="Google_Cloud_Platform_Service--google_app_engine">
         <div class="material-radio__circle"></div>
         <div class="material-radio__fill"></div>
         <span class="contact-form-label
...

Comment: <label class="cc" for="abuse_date">
   <span class="contact-form-label__text">Abuse date</span>
</label>
<input aria-label="Abuse date" id="abuse_date" name="abuse_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field" data-contact-form-field-required="true" data-enable-form-single-attachments="true" data-frd-context-type="TYPE_CORE" data-frd-context-type-number="15" data-frd-identifier="IDENTIFIER_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION" data-frd-identifier-number="8000020" data-frd-v2-identifier="IDENTIFIER_ISSUE_DESCRIPTION" data-frd-v2-identifier-number="8000020" data-frd-value-type="VALUE

Comment: <div class="field" data-enable-form-single-attachments="true" data-frd-context-type="TYPE_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-context-type-number="0" data-frd-identifier="IDENTIFIER_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-identifier-number="0" data-frd-v2-identifier="IDENTIFIER_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-v2-identifier-number="0" data-frd-value-type="VALUE_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED" data-frd-value-type-number="0" data-page="1" data-type="HIDDEN" data-use-new-uploads-component-for-cufs="true">
   <input name="Subject" value="Google Cloud Platform Abuse Report" type="hidden">
</div>
<div class="alert-area"></div>
<div class="button-bar"

Comment: sorry but also posting the relevant part, I hit the max chars limits. You can see the html by going to URL: "https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report". I have no access to server side Google Apache web server

Comment: You can edit the question, reading code in comments is difficult.

Comment: You could setup a fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) between your browser and the server to see what is being exchanged.